# UltraGrid add BindingList<MyClass> and map property names to column names

Tags: bindinglist, ultrawingrid

Is it possible to map the property names of my class to the column names of the UltraGrid control?

MyClass is for example a user class:

```
class User
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }

BindingList<User> myList = new BindingList<User>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          this.ultraGrid1.DataSource = myList;
      }
```

This works, but the colum names will be overwritten with the property names of my class.
Is there a way to map the property names to colum names?

I tried this by using DataBindings, but this did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Why yes, yes there is!

The [`DisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) attribute in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace:

```
class User
{
    [DisplayName("Identifier")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can also do the following in the InitializeLayout event:

```
 e.Layout.Bands(0).Column("Name").Header.Caption = "First Name";
```